# Bash rename files based on XML

Tags: xml, bash, xml-parsing, xmllint

I am in the process of making a bash script and I need to rename all files of a particular file type (in this case svg) in order to reflect the order in which they are mentioned in an xml file.

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><manifest identifier="id1" version="2006-01" smartnotebook:filesource="SMART Notebook for Mac Version=11.3.804.0" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3" xmlns:smartnotebook="http://www.smarttech.com/2006-01/notebook" xmlns:smartgallery="http://www.smarttech.com/2006-01/gallery"><metadata><schema>ADL SCORM</schema><schemaversion>CAM 1.3</schemaversion><adlcp:location>metadata.xml</adlcp:location></metadata><organizations><organization id="pagegroups"><item id="group0" identifierref="group0_pages"><title>Group 1</title></item></organization></organizations><resources><resource identifier="group0_pages" href="page4.svg" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="asset">*******<file href="page4.svg"/><file href="page0.svg"/><file href="page1.svg"/><file href="page3.svg"/><file href="page2.svg"/>********</resource><resource identifier="pages" href="page4.svg" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="asset"><file href="page4.svg"/><file href="page0.svg"/><file href="page1.svg"/><file href="page3.svg"/><file href="page2.svg"/></resource><resource identifier="images"/><resource identifier="sounds"/><resource identifier="attachments"/><resource identifier="flash"/><resource identifier="videos"/><resource identifier="annotationmetadata"/><resource identifier="brush"/></resources></manifest>`

I need it to read this file(and other files in the same format) and (for example) rename page4.svg to file0.svg ... and page0.svg to file1.svg. I have been investigating how to do this via xmllint but my xpath knowledge is very limited. Anything is helpfull!
thanks!

Comment: I got to xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name() = "file"]/@href' ... but not really working the way it should be

Comment: [Please update your original question to include the command, the actual output, and the expected output](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't worry, you'll probably get an answer as soon as people have enough to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath query `//resource/file/@href` will give you the list of hrefs. But there will be duplicates based on that xml sample. If you just want the list from the first resource you could use `//resource[1]/file/@href` or specify by the identifier as `//resource[@identifier="group0_pages"]/file/@href`.

However, for some reason I was unable to get xmllint to accept those queries even though they are correct and they work in other tools. Instead, in Linux, I use the `xpath` utility which is  a perl script from the `libxml-xpath-perl` package. Along with some simple parsing, an example bash script would look like:

```
i=0
while read filename; do
        mv $filename file$i.svg
        let i++
done < <(xpath -q -e '//resource[@identifier="group0_pages"]/file/@href' input.xml | cut -d\" -f2)
```

Comment: hm, I am getting a "Cannot open file Filename.xml' at /usr/share/perl5/XML/XPath.pm line 53." error... I even made it so it had the full path.
for example I know  '/home/koru/.temp/SmartConvert/Total War 1914/imsmanifest.xml' exists

Comment: @LnkusCapricornius  Did you surround the file name with `""`? That path has spaces in it so you'll need to quote it.

Comment: And no, with the quotes it does some weird stuff and doesn't work